# Can't create relationship OneToMany

Tags: entity-relationship, entities

I have below code:

Entity User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User extends AbstractModel{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private long userId;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="createdBy", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Address> loans = new HashSet<Address>();'
```

Entity Address:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private long addressId;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private User createdBy;
```

And there is a problem because when I want to try save User into database I dont have an Entry for Address(in DB of course). 
I would like to create an automatic Address entry creation when User is saved...
Maybe someone had this kind of problem and coult help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think name of joinColumn should be USER_ID.
Could you try?

Comment: Thanks for your post...Itried also with USER_ID but unfortunately result is the same...No entry for Addresss table i db :)
Btw I've edited my post to "USER_ID" in joincolumn

Comment: I can tell one mmore that I dont have foreigh keys in db...Maybe this couse this missbehaviour

Comment: Foreign key is not required.  Are you sure there is at least one item in Set loans from User class before you save the User instance ?